# Loading specific foreign key attribute in Django Template

Tags: html, django, for-loop, templates

Devs,

I have a 2 Models and one of them have a foreign key attribute as a reference to the other. Now I am trying to view both objects in my Template.

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "product.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ItemDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['markets'] = Market.objects.all()
        # And so on for more models
        return context
```

In my template I just want the exact market for my product

I tryed something like this:

```
      {% for market in markets %}  // or {% for object.market in markets %} 
  
      {% if market.market == object.market %}

     >> Do smth if conditions match << 

      {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
```

In the loop I get strings like x1, x2, x3 and object.market have the value x1.

So I just want to output the object for the corresponding market.
But if I check {% if market.market == object.market %} the conditions somehow don't match. When I print them out inside the loop I get x1,x2,x3,... for market.market and x1,x1,x1,... for object.market

These are my models:

```
class Market(models.Model):
    market = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    branch = models.CharField(choices=BRANCH_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.market

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("core:market-product-list", kwargs={
        'slug': self.slug
    })

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market, related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ItemCategory, related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    path = models.CharField(default='/market-product-list/', max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField()
```

Comment: The models please.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the issue. The problem was that object.market is interpreted as an object not as a string. So it was impossible to check the conditions in the if-clause. I managed to output the corresponding market with converting the object to a string like this:

At first:
`{% if object.market|slugify|capfirst == market.market %}`
and then changed it to simply
 `{% if object.market == market %}`
which is obviously the better solution

PS: I also learned that this is bad programming I should not filter in a Template but I am new to Django and I am glad that things are working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Just call the field for the particular market as in the model.

```
 {% for market in markets %}  // or {% for object.market in markets %} 

  {% if market.market == object.market %}

 {{ market.fieldname }} 

  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That won't work for me since the output of market.market is x1, x2 and the output of object.market is x1,x1

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you loop through Product(Item) objects?

Comment: I just have one item on that DetailView. My goal is to display the referenced market.